# Firebase run script after retrieving existing data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function in js that needs to refresh after I retrieve data from Firebase.

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + this.userId + '/info').on('child_added', function(snapshot){
    this.myFunction();
}.bind(this));
```

The problem is that the data in Firebase is very large so I don't what to run the function lots of times. This is how I what it to run:

1. Retrieve ALL EXISTING data from Firebase.
2. Run the function (once).
3. Every time more data comes in from Firebase, run the function again.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yevgen's answer is one way to do this. But it means you'll be processing all children on each change, which may not be what you want.

An alternative is to process the initial children using a `value` event and then the subsequent changes with `child_` events. You can use the guarantee that the `value` event will fire after all the related `child_` events to detect whether the initial payload is done.

```
var isInitialValueDone = false

ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log('Do something with '+child.key);
  });
  isInitialValueDone = true;
});
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  if (isInitialValueDone) {
    console.log('Do something with '+snapshot.key);
  }
});
```

Comment: Just changed the first 'on' to 'once'. with your answer I don't need to restructure my data layout.

Comment: Ouch... good point about the `once()`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible. First you need to left empty `ref` parameter, so you get all info from root node(all your data). It will trigger at first time it runs by default and will trigger again on any data change, because of parameter`'value'`. Instead of you you may use child_added, child_changed, child_removed or child_moved to reduce number of times of receiving data from firebase. Example:

```
firebase.database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot){
    myFunction(snapshot.val());
};
```

P.S. Don't forget to exact data from snapshot with `snapshot.val()`.

Comment: I like this, its creative. so I can put my node in another one, like this:  firebase.database().ref('/users/' + this.userId + '/main/info')

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to retrieve all existing data from firebase at once then as more data comes in listen for those data changes. If that is your case look at the method once() in firebase

Comment: yea, but I well need to run a 'on' function after the once is finished. how do I do that?