# on('child_added' VS once('child_added

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it supposed to be any difference on running this two codes?

```
ref.on('child_added',function(child,prev){
 console.log(child.key+prev);
}
ref.off();
```

and

```
ref.once('child_added',function(child,prev){
 console.log(child.key+prev);
}
```

I've been surprised that the second one doesn't iterates between the childs!

What am I doing wrong here (edited->)**to obtain a complete list of the childs**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `once`, you're asking for a single event of the indicated type. So `once("child_added"` fires a single `child_added` event.

The fact that your `on` fires multiple times, is likely a race condition because of the way you ordered the calls. I'd expect this to also invoke only once:

```
ref.on('child_added',function(child,prev){
  console.log(child.key+prev);
  ref.off();
}
```

But I must admit this is pretty uncommon, so I don't think I ever tested it.

Comment: Ok, then... Isn't there a way to call ALL the childs one time with some alternative to "on"? (because... when there's already another "on" to the same Ref which shouldn't be turned off, and I turn off this new one, the first one shuts down too; and if I don't shut down this new "on", it runs twice on recall of the function which includes it)

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - it's hard to help more with just the snippet you shared. In general: you should call `off()` when you want to stop listening, but are not exiting the process (i.e. navigating away from the web page if that's your platform). If you only want to get the initial children of a collection, you can use a combination of `child_added` and `value` listeners. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969411/firebase-run-script-after-retrieving-existing-data/38976115#38976115

Comment: So I guess that to create an iteration between childs of a Ref (with unknown keys) I should call the Ref `once` with `value`, and iterate between the resulting `val()` with a normal JS `for(x in child.val())` ... right?

Comment: If you want to loop over all query results only once (instead of synchronizing it continuously), you could use `once("value", snapshot => snapshot.forEach(child => console.log(child.val()))`.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect... Do you know if there's any contest for Progressive WebApp's (based on FireBase)?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Puf's answer I would add this quote from documentation you should be aware:

> Add queries to limit the data that your listen operations return and
>   use listeners that only download updates to data — for example, on()
>   instead of once(). Reserve .once() for actions that truly don’t
>   require data updates.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize

Another usefull link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing

Comment: Correct, it's indeed an important thing to note, since those **on()** functions stay open and download content whenever it's changed even if your user is in a different view that doesn't uses it. What we've done as policy when working with firebase is all **on()** functions specific to a view are saved as reference in an array that close them all whenever changing a view.